# Semi partial correlation importance variables

Tags: data-transformation, sas, logarithm, partial-correlation

I have some SAS code that is used to calculate the importance of variables using semi-partial correlations:

```
data estimate; 
  set estimate; 
  trans_SqPartCorrTypeII = - log10(1 - SqPartCorrTypeII); 
run;
```

What does the following mean: `- log10(1 - SqPartCorrTypeII)`?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Is this part of the SAS output?

Comment: data estimate;
set estimate;
 trans_SqPartCorrTypeII = - log10(1 - SqPartCorrTypeII);
run;

Comment: it takes SqPartCorrTypeII form the output of a proc reg...but don't know what the purpose of the transformation is?